# Assigning multiple css rule's to an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is few line of java script code to create a div element dynamically. But my doubt is after create that element, is there any short-cut way to assign multiple css rules instead of typing (container.style) again and again.

```
<script>
    (function(){
        window.onload = function(){
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.style.width = '500px';
            container.style.height = '200px';
            container.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            container.style.margin = '0 auto';

            document.body.appendChild(container);
        }
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you define the styles in CSS?

Comment: Look into jQuery, it has a method `.css()` which you can use to apply many css styles.

Comment: In jquery it is very easy. but is there any short-cut for javascript also.

Answer (score 5):

Use a CSS class and assign the class to the element:

```
.MyClass {
   width: 500px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then `container.className = "MyClass";`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop to iterate over an object, applying the properties to the style property one-by-one:

```
(function(){
    window.onload = function(){
        var container = document.createElement('div'),
            styles = {
                "width": "500px",
                "height": "200px",
                "backgroundColor": "red",
                "margin": "0 auto"
            },
            i;
        for (i in styles) {
            container.style[i] = styles[i];
        }

        document.body.appendChild(container);
    }
}());​
```

It's worth noting that this is longer than the original code :-p If you wrap the `for` loop in another function and re-use the function repeatedly it could be useful. If you find yourself needing this repeatedly, I would highly recommend including [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or [ZeptoJS](http://zeptojs.com/)) and using [`.css(…)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to apply the CSS. jQuery does several transformations to the properties as it applies them… It changes hyphens in the property names to the correct camel casing, makes changes to apply the correct properties or property values for IE, etc. It makes the coding much easier, and any future code maintainers will benefit from that ease as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
                container.setAttribute("id","div1");
                document.body.appendChild(container);

$("#div1").css({"width":"500px","height":"200px","background-color":"red"});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/bc9Hn/)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `css` function:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        window.onload = function(){
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            css(container,
                {'width': '500px',
                 'height': '200px',
                 'backgroundColor': 'red',
                 'margin': '0 auto'});

            document.body.appendChild(container);
        }

        function css(element, style){
            for(key in style){
                if(style.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    element.style[key] = style[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }());
</script>
```

You can then re-use the `css()` function for other elements.